# iOS TableView Calling numberOfRowsInSection repetitively

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

I set the`TableView` data source and delegate programmatically and have also added the necessary code to the header file of the view controller.

After hardcoding the`numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView` methods to both return 1 and adding corresponding logs, I noticed that both methods are repetitively called (4 times) but the method`cellForRowAtIndexPath` doesn't get called once.

The`TableView` doesn't appear on screen but I assume that is because there aren't cells being presented, but after hardcoding values for everything including the`cellLabel` text, I don't understand how those two methods could be called over and over again but skip over the`cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

The log looks like this:

> 2015-05-20 22:39:09.595 SchoolAnalytics[28419:2137236] # of sections
>
> 2015-05-20 22:39:09.595 SchoolAnalytics[28419:2137236] Number of rows
>   for section 0
>
> 2015-05-20 22:39:09.595 SchoolAnalytics[28419:2137236] # of sections
>
> 2015-05-20 22:39:09.595 SchoolAnalytics[28419:2137236] Number of rows
>   for section 0
>
> 2015-05-20 22:39:09.598 SchoolAnalytics[28419:2137236] # of sections
>
> 2015-05-20 22:39:09.598 SchoolAnalytics[28419:2137236] Number of rows
>   for section 0
>
> 2015-05-20 22:39:09.598 SchoolAnalytics[28419:2137236] # of sections
>
> 2015-05-20 22:39:09.598 SchoolAnalytics[28419:2137236] Number of rows
>   for section 0

How I load the cells:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    targetList.delegate = self;
    targetList.dataSource = self;

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     }

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
     NSLog(@"# of sections");
     return 1;    //count of section
 }


 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     NSLog(@"Number of rows for section %li", (long)section);
     return 1;
 }



 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    NSLog(@"CELL FOR ROW");
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
     {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
     }

     // Here we use the provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
     // Ensure you use a placeholder image otherwise cells will be initialized with no image

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Cell 1";
    return cell;
           }
```

My header file has the two delegates

```
     @interface ClassViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

It might be important to mention that this isn't the root view, it is presented with a segue, and upon loading this view, a subview is added at the top which is a subclass of UIView and has to be drawn.

Comment: Let me know how you load cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: You could add some code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

`numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView` are called whenever you call `reloadData` on your table view.

Comment: I didn't ever call reloadData myself, and if I did shouldn't the cellForRowAtIndexPath be called too since I'm returning 1 for the number of rows per section?

Answer (score 0):

These delegate method `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView` are call each time you load data. Like if you call `[table reloadData]` 5 times these methods call each time.